# How to send a HTTPS 0.9 request from the command line?

Tags: http, ssl, curl, https

I'm trying to reproduce an odd bug that we believe may be caused by our load balancers trying to check the status of our services, with requests using HTTP/0.9. The service is only configured to use HTTPS, so they are being sent as HTTP/0.9 over HTTPS.

I could use use telnet to send a HTTP/0.9 request, but we have to use HTTPS so that doesn't work. My usual go-to tool for this kind of thing is cURL, but it doesn't look like cURL supports sending 0.9 requests (for good reasons, I know).

What could I use to generate a HTTP/0.9 GET request over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use openssl. First establish the SSL connection:

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect ip:port
CONNECTED
...
lots of output, certificate etc
```

And then send the request

```
GET /
[empty line]
```